# Iphone doesn't read well resolution targetting and icons on a redirected domain, but it works in original subfolder?

Tags: iphone, css, dns, responsive-design, media-queries

Something weird is happening with targetting for phone resolutions, at least with my iphone 4s:

I have this domain www.marialluisaperez.es that redirects to www.pauperez.es/marialluisaperez/ (so I only pay one hosting service for 2 domains..).

I've never had issues until now, when I've applied the media queries to make adapt the site to small screens. The thing is, if I resize the navigator for whatever page in www.marialluisaperez.es, it changes correctly, but when I look at it in the iphone, it's as if the iphone didn't recognize this queries. Also, if I save the webpage in my iphone it doesn't read that there are icons I specified (, etc.)

And it's weirder because instead, if I go directly to www.pauperez.es/marialluisaperez/ with my iphone, then it works! It loads the correct CSS tags for that screen resolutions, and if I save it, it recognizes the icons prepared.

So what is going on here?? It is weird that on a laptop there's never a problem and with the iphone (haven't checked with other phones) there's a problem only with www.marialluisaperez.es, and not with www.pauperez.es/marialluisaperez/, which is where that domain links to...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a `DOCTYPE` set on the main site.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @TheCapn How is that not the answer? Without a DOCTYPE, nothing in the website can be expected to function.

Comment: I just went to the hosting site and see what happens: the redirection assigns a frameset in order to maintain the marialluisaperez.es domain when it redirects it. I don't know if there's much I can do there because I don't have a hosting plan for that domain, that's why I redirect it, and the hosting company provides the redirection and the only way to mantain the marialluisaperez.es domain name when it redirects is to use a pre-made frameset option that I can't control.